# How to JOIN a table with itself while using a sub-query?

Tags: mysql, join, select, subquery, mariadb-10.5

I `JOIN` a table to itself as

```
SELECT t1.TagID AS TagID1
    ,t2.TagID AS TagID2
    ,COUNT(1)
FROM TagMap AS t1
JOIN TagMap AS t2 ON t1.ArticleID = t2.ArticleID AND t1.TagID <> t2.TagID
GROUP BY t1.TagID, t2.TagID
```

How can I limit the rows retrieved for each table (t1 and t2) by

```
WHERE TagID IN(SELECT TagID FROM Tags WHERE Articles>50)
```

Note that the table `TagMap` is huge with over 200M rows, and I wish to limit its size before `JOIN`.

In fact, the reason I want to limit the number of rows of `TagMap` is that the table is too big and I cannot perform the `JOIN`.

Comment: Changing `<>` to `<` will cut out the redundant rows and speed it up by 2x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a subselect query as basis for t1 and t2

Like

```
SELECT 
    t1.TagID AS TagID1, t2.TagID AS TagID2, COUNT(1)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        TagMap
    WHERE
        TagID IN (SELECT 
                TagID
            FROM
                Tags
            WHERE
                Articles > 50)) AS t1
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        TagMap
    WHERE
        TagID IN (SELECT 
                TagID
            FROM
                Tags
            WHERE
                Articles > 50)) AS t2 ON t1.ArticleID = t2.ArticleID
        AND t1.TagID <> t2.TagID
GROUP BY t1.TagID , t2.TagID
```

Comment: `INDEX(Articles, TagID)` may help.